# Fire trigger for every inserted row using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, triggers, sqlbulkcopy

I am using `SqlBulkCopy` class to insert 50k rows at a time in table `tbl_records`
I have set a `After Insert` trigger on this table and using following code

```
SqlBulkCopy SqlBc1 = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers);

// Set DataReader For SqlBulkCopy

sqlComm = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlTemCon);
sqlComm.CommandTimeout = 3600000;
sqlComm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
SqlDataReader dReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();       
SqlBc1.WriteToServer(dReader);
```

But after execution of prog. It fire trigger for only `First`  row out of 50k inserted

I wanna it should fire for every row. How can i do this??

Comment: I have already checked that answer but in my case after adding `SqlBulkCopyOptions` still it is firing trigger for only first row inserted out of 50k rows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805413/how-can-i-get-a-trigger-to-fire-on-each-inserted-row-during-an-insert-into-table

Answer (score 9):

Triggers never fire per-row. They fire for all rows of the corresponding DML statement. Rewrite your trigger so that it can cope with the `INSERTED` table containing many rows. This is best-practice and required practice anyway.

> it is firing trigger for only first row inserted out of 50k rows

You must be misinterpreting the situation, maybe because you were unaware that triggers can contain multiple rows in the virtual tables.

Answer (score 5):

In case another person come across this problem and looking for a solution, here I will post my findings as well.

**IMPORTANT**: usr has already given the answer, but I will explain it a little bit.

First, this is what Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says about bulk insert,

> If FIRE_TRIGGERS is not specified, no insert triggers execute.
>
> FIRE_TRIGGERS Specifies that any insert triggers defined on the
>   destination table execute during the bulk-import operation. If
>   triggers are defined for INSERT operations on the target table, they
>   are fired for every completed batch.

`FIRE_TRIGGERS` is a argument use with `BULK INSERT` T-SQL statement.

And if you are trying to use bulk insert with `SqlBulkCopy`class (.Net Framework/Core) you have to use `SqlBulkCopyOptions` Enum ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions?view=netframework-4.8)).

> You can use the SqlBulkCopyOptions enumeration when you construct a
>   SqlBulkCopy instance to change how the WriteToServer methods for that
>   instance behave.

Here is a sample,

```
var options = SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints | SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity;
var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, options);
```

OK. Now triggers will run with bulk insert, But why for only one record. Read what Microsoft said about `FIRE_TRIGGER` argument again.

> If triggers are defined for INSERT operations on the target table,
>   they are fired for every completed batch.

That means, your trigger will run for whole batch at once. But your batch contains more than one row. Therefore your trigger algorithm (The thing you supposed to do to a single record)  will work for one record, not for all the records.

Now you know why it doesn't work for all, so the solution is improve your trigger to work with multiple rows. Which means iterate throw all rows comes with `INSERTED` temporary table and execute your algorithm for all records. You can use `CURSOR` or a simple `WHILE LOOP`. Its up to you.

You can find examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-dml-triggers-to-handle-multiple-rows-of-data?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 4):

The SqlBulkCopy object's batch size is the full set of rows, by default.

Here's what MSDN says about the BatchSize property values:
"Zero (the default) indicates that each WriteToServer operation is a single batch."

In this case, the trigger will fire once, but the Inserted table will have entries for all of the affected records.

Answer (score 0):

I Have try this and it will work for.

I hope its help you..

`CREATE TRIGGER Triggername ON TableName
After INSERT 
AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON;`

insert into TargetTable
       (Fields) 
       SELECT (i.field1,i.field2,i.field3,....,i.fieldn)
    FROM
        inserted i
GO