# Modify SQL Trigger to work with BULK INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Trigger that doesn't fire because the records in the table are inserted through a BULK INSERT. I do not have access to the code that inserts the records so I need to modify this trigger to handle the BULK INSERT. This is the trigger:

```
    USE [testdata]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_test] ON [dbo].[test]
    AFTER INSERT , UPDATE
AS 

BEGIN

    DECLARE @BatchId int, @Ethanol decimal(18,6), @Glucose decimal(18,6), @SampleAge varchar(50);

    SELECT @BatchId = CONVERT(int,bd.[BatchId]),
           @Ethanol = CONVERT(decimal(18,2),[Ethanol]), 
           @Glucose= CONVERT(decimal(18,2),[Glucose]), 
           @SampleAge = bd.SampleCode
    from INSERTED bd

    update [dbo].[DeSchedule] 
    SET 
            [Ethanol] = @Ethanol,
            [Glucose] = @Glucose,
            [SampleCompleted] = 1 
    WHERE [BatchID] = @BatchId AND [SampleAge] = @SampleAge
END
```

Can anyone help me in modifying this trigger to handle the BULK INSERT.

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. it assumes that the inserted table will only ever have a single row. Triggers are fired per operation not per row. And BULK INSERT means you are almost always going to have multiple rows. You need set based logic, not scalar logic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002947/fire-trigger-for-every-inserted-row-using-sqlbulkcopy

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.  There could be/probably is more than one row in  INSERTED. (as previously stated).  Please do not write a "theres only one row" type of trigger.  Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.

Answer (score 9):

Unless you can modify the BULK INSERT statement you are stuck. By default triggers do NOT run during a bulk insert. You must explicitly turn them on in the command with the [FIRE_TRIGGER option](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql#fire_triggers).

Answer (score 3):

Only need to edit BULK INSERT File below:

```
BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
   FROM 'f:\orders\lineitem.tbl'
   WITH
     (
         FIELDTERMINATOR =' |'
         , ROWTERMINATOR = ':\n'
         , FIRE_TRIGGERS
      );
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [testdata]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_test] ON [dbo].[test]
    AFTER INSERT , UPDATE
AS 

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @BatchId int, @Ethanol decimal(18,6), @Glucose decimal(18,6), @SampleAge varchar(50);

    Declare CurI cursor for 
    SELECT [BatchId],[Ethanol] ,[Glucose], SampleCode  from INSERTED

    Open CurI
        fetch next from CurI into @BatchId,@Ethanol,@Glucose, @SampleAge
        while @@fetch_status=0
        Begin
            update [dbo].[DeSchedule] 
            SET 
                    [Ethanol] = @Ethanol,
                    [Glucose] = @Glucose,
                    [SampleCompleted] = 1 
            WHERE [BatchID] = @BatchId AND [SampleAge] = @SampleAge
  
            Fetch next from CurI into @BatchId,@Ethanol,@Glucose, @SampleAge
         End

    Close CurI
    Deallocate CurI

    
END
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is it selected only the last row of the inserted table ,i think  if you change the query like this it would work

```
update [dbo].[DeSchedule] 
    SET 
            [Ethanol] =(select CONVERT(int,bd.[Ethanol]) from inserted bd),
            [Glucose] = (select CONVERT(decimal(18,2),[Glucose]) from inserted bd),
            [SampleCompleted] = 1 
    WHERE [BatchID] = (select CONVERT(int,bd.[BatchId]) from inserted bd) AND [SampleAge] = (select bd.SampleCode from inserted bd)
```