# SQL Server 2008 - Insert ID from newly created record in one table, into two other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreach, cursor

I have three tables:

```
DECLARE @UserTable TABLE(
        [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        UserName varchar(100))

DECLARE @UserRoles TABLE(
        [UserRoleId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        RoleName varchar(100),
        UserId int)

DECLARE @UserProjects TABLE(
        [UserProjectId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        ProjectName varchar(100),
        UserId int)
```

What I want to do, is that whenever I create a new record in `@UserTable`, I want to take the ID from that record and create a new record in `@UserRoles` and `@UserProjects`.  Inserting records on a one-by-one basis, I can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get the new ID, and then do the 2nd and 3rd inserts using the value from that...

But when I try to do this with something like 100 records being inserted into @UserTable, it won't work because it is a bulk insert.  What is the best way to go about this?  Use a cursor?  I'm open to ideas, as I've never had to do this before...it would be simple with a `FOREACH loop`, but as far as I know, SQL doesn't handle these in the same way we would expect Java or C# to, right?

Comment: You will need to create After Insert Trigger on UserTable which will handle any number of Inserts into that table will do cascading inserts into other tables.

Comment: @muhammed-ali

I'm not sure I understand.  I have a stored procedure that creates a temp table, inserts an initial value into it, and then updates that table with information.  Then, I take all records in the temp table, and insert them into another table (the users table).  I want to create a trigger to go off on the user table insert, which will then populate the roles and projects table...but I keep getting errors when creating the trigger. Where is the best place to put the trigger, with other code in the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm mistaken, what you're trying to do is enforce referrential integrity on your tables and account for cascading actions.  There's a decent article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902684%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) that shows how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an INSERT TRIGGER like so. When new rows get inserted into your Users Table, this trigger will "fire" for each statement (not each row) executed. So in case of a BULK Insert, we have to use a temp table variable that will hold all the newly inserted Users IDs and then perform inserts into the UserRoles and UserProjects table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Insert_Role_And_Project
ON [UserTable]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
    Declare @NewUserIDsTable TABLE
    ( NewUserID INT NOT NULL )

    INSERT INTO @NewUserIDsTable SELECT ID FROM INSERTED

    INSERT INTO UserRoles (UserId, RoleName) 
    SELECT NewUserID, 'Default Role' 
    FROM @NewUserIDsTable 


    INSERT INTO UserProjects (UserId, ProjectName) 
    SELECT NewUserID, 'Default Project'
    FROM @NewUserIDsTable 

End
```

Do the RoleName and ProjectName in the @UserRoles and @UserProject tables have default values? For this code sample, I've used default values of `'Default Role'` and `'Default Project'`.

Comment: select @NewUserId=UserId FROM INSERTED will not work with a bulk insert (multiple records in inserted)

Comment: The three tables were just arbitrarily made up for the sake of the question being asked, but I get what you mean.  Essentially, I need to create a blank record in the other 2 tables whenever a new user is created, and then at a later time during user registration, those two tables will be updated (this way, the record already exists, as registration doesn't have to be completed in one sitting as per customer requirements).

Comment: @Alain_Deloin You are correct. I fixed the Trigger to address bulk insert scenario. For background see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5806230/325521

Comment: The reason I used a temp table see here what your code does :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fc64/1

Comment: @SalarianEngineer Agreed. I removed that suggestion from my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a trigger on your UserTable  which will do cascading insert into the other tables for you some thing like this

```
CREATE Trigger tr_ForInserts
ON UserTable
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

   /*Get all the new insert into a temp table */

   SELECT * INTO #TempTable 
   FROM inserted 

 /*Insert Statement to Insert recods in UserRoles Table */

   INSERT INTO UserRoles (Column1,Column2,Column3,...) 
   SELECT  Column1,Column2,Column3
   FROM #TempTable 


 /*Insert Statement to Insert recods in UserProjects Table */ 

   INSERT INTO UserProjects (Column4,Column5,Column6,...) 
   SELECT  Column4,Column5,Column6
   FROM #TempTable 

END
```

Comment: There is no need to create a temp table and select everything into it, since the OP wants only the ID.

Comment: @Shiva The reason I used a temp table see here what your code does :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fc64/1

Comment: Agreed. I updated my code to address BULK INSERTs. Still, you should be using a TABLE variable, not temp table (more overhead, bigger scope etc). :)

Comment: @Shiva Table variables are good and faster if you know you will be only inserting small number of rows but what if you have to insert lots of rows which might end up eating all of your memory ??? will you go into your trigger's definition and tweak it everytime you have to do big number of bulk inserts ?? or will you do some calculation and let all your users know how many rows they can add at one time ??? or is it better to use temp tables and let sql server do the work :)

Comment: @Shiva: table variables are populated in tempdb like temp tables, and trigger logical tables (inserted and deleted)  also go in tempdb, so that makes twice the data in tempdb in an insert trigger (x3 for update trigger). There is no advantage using temp tables variables than temp tables (Inside sql server K.Delaney) and others : http://cybersql.blogspot.fr/2009/12/yes-table-variables-and-temp-tables.html

Comment: also on Temp tables if you are dealing with a lot of data you can create indexes to speed up the operations and yes I should have Dropped the table at the end of all the operations. But I guess we all are trying to put OP in the right direction, cant give him the code he can copy paste in his database to make it work, with the information provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

With real Tables (and not variables) you can create a trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTable( [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, UserName varchar(100))

CREATE TABLE UserRoles ( [UserRoleId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, RoleName varchar(100), UserId int)

CREATE TABLE UserProjects ( [UserProjectId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, ProjectName varchar(100), UserId int)

GO

if object_id('UserTableTrigger') is not null
    drop trigger UserTableTrigger
go
create trigger UserTableTrigger ON Usertable
for INSERT
as
begin
    insert into UserRoles(RoleName,UserId)
    select 'Role_'+UserName, inserted.UserId
    from inserted
    insert into UserProjects(ProjectName,UserId)
    select 'Project_'+UserName, inserted.UserId
    from inserted
end
go
```

If you want to check it:

```
insert into UserTable (UserName)
select 'User_'+name from master..spt_values

select * from UserTable
left join UserRoles on UserTable.USerId = UserRoles.UserId
left join UserProjects on UserTable.USerId = UserProjects.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
-- Parameters
DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(100), @RoleName VARCHAR(100), @ProjectName VARCHAR(100);
SELECT  @UserName = 'User CocoJambo',
        @RoleName = 'Role MamboJambo',
        @ProjectName = 'Project Jumbo';
-- End of Parameters

DECLARE @NewUserID TABLE (UserID INT);

INSERT  @UserTable (UserName)
OUTPUT  inserted.UserId INTO @NewUserID (UserID)
VALUES  (@UserName);

INSERT  @UserRoles (UserID, RoleName)
SELECT  u.UserId, @RoleName
FROM    @UserTable u;

INSERT  @UserProjects (UserId, ProjectName)
SELECT  u.UserId, @ProjectName
FROM    @UserTable u;
```

Comment: If this solutions doesn't help you then you should provide more infos: for example what data (what columns) do you import ? Do you import one or more files into SQL Server DB (one file per table maybe) ?