# How to create trigger for each row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2014

```
create table t1(col int);
create table t2(col int);


CREATE TRIGGER tr
ON t1
AFTER INSERT 
as
    begin
    INSERT INTO t2(col) values(1)
end;

-- tables and trigger created

INSERT INTO t1(col) values(1), (2)
```

When I run this insert query, in table `t2` insert event happens just once.

Needed `FOR EACH ROW` statement in trigger, but how to make this in SQL Server? Not found in documentation, and after googling, not found some good solution also.

Comment: SQL Server does not support row level triggers

Comment: If you really need them you must work with cursors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805413/how-can-i-get-a-trigger-to-fire-on-each-inserted-row-during-an-insert-into-table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Dear using INSERTED table you can work row by row. Or I don't understand the question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a feature that's just not present in the product - you cannot "magically" make it appear...

Comment: Sounds more like an xy problem.  Why do you need a row-by-row trigger?   Just about anything you could want to do can be done in a set-based way with the table trigger.    What are you trying to achieve, @otariki?

Comment: if you need to do *something* to every row in the table when you insert a row into the table, could you not accomplish this by executing a stored procedure within a trigger?

Answer (score 3):

Replace your: `INSERT INTO t2(col) values(1)`

in:

`INSERT INTO t2(col) SELECT col FROM inserted`

Because in `inserted` table you'll find all rows inserted in table linked at your trigger (t1)