# AFTER INSERT trigger causes query execution to hang up

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, triggers

In a ms sql database I have a table named **combo** where multiple inserts, updates and deletes can happen (as well as single, of course). In another table named **migrimi_temp** I keep track of these changes in the form of queries (query that would have to be executed in mysql to achieve the same result).

For example, if a delete query is performed for all rows where id > 50, the trigger should activate to store the following query into the log table:

> DELETE FROM combo where id > 50;

Therefore this one delete query in the combo table would result in one row in the log table.

But if instead I have an insert query inserting 2 rows, a trigger should activate to store each insert into the log table. So this one insert query in the combo table would result into 2 new rows in the log table.

I intend to handle insert, update and delete actions into separated triggers. I had managed to write triggers for single row insert / update/ delete. Then it occurred to me that multiple actions might be performed too.

This is my attempt to handle the case of multiple inserts in one single query. I resorted to using cursors after not being able to adapt the initial trigger without a cursor. The trigger is executed successfully, but when I perform an insert (single or multiple rows) the execution hangs up indefinitely, or at least longer than reasonable .

```
USE [migrimi_test]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[c_combo]    Script Date: 12/11/2017 5:33:46 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create TRIGGER [dbo].[u_combo]
ON [migrimi_test].[dbo].[combo]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @c_id INT;
    DECLARE @c_name nvarchar(100);
    DECLARE @c_duration int;
    DECLARE @c_isavailable INT;

    DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
      SELECT id, name, duration, isvisible FROM inserted
    OPEN c
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @c_id, @c_name, @c_duration, @c_isavailable
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    INSERT INTO [migrimi_temp].[dbo].[sql_query] (query)
    VALUES ('INSERT INTO combo (id, name, duration, value, isavailable, createdAt, updatedAt) values ('+CAST(@c_id as nvarchar(50))+', '+'"'+@c_name+'"'+', 
    '+CAST(@c_duration as nvarchar(50))+', 1, '+CAST(@c_isavailable as nvarchar(50))+', Now(), Now());' )

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @c_id, @c_name, @c_duration, @c_isavailable
    CLOSE c
    END
    DEALLOCATE c

GO
```

SQL server version is 2012. OS is windows server 2008 (though I doubt that is relevant). I was based mainly on these two resources: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/40f5635c-9034-4e9b-8fd5-c02cec44ce86/how-to-let-trigger-act-for-each-row?forum=sqlgetstarted

and [How can I get a trigger to fire on each inserted row during an INSERT INTO Table (etc) SELECT * FROM Table2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805413/how-can-i-get-a-trigger-to-fire-on-each-inserted-row-during-an-insert-into-table)

This is part of a larger idea I am trying to accomplish, and until 2 days ago I was totally unfamiliar with triggers. I am trying to balance learning with accomplishing in reasonable amounts of time, but not doing so great

Comment: With enough code, this can be accomplished. I can't help but think that putting a cursor (already a not best practice) inside of a trigger (not a great practice) will lead to much heartache and bad performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursors are notoriously slow in SQL Server. 
Instead of using a cursor to loop over the inserted table, you can use `insert...select` which is a set based approach. It is much faster and is the recommended way to work in SQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[u_combo]
ON [migrimi_test].[dbo].[combo]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [migrimi_temp].[dbo].[sql_query] (query)
    SELECT 'INSERT INTO combo (id, name, duration, value, isavailable, createdAt, updatedAt) values ('+CAST(id as nvarchar(50))+', "'+ name +'", 
        '+ CAST(duration as nvarchar(50)) +', 1, '+ CAST(isvisible as nvarchar(50))+ ', Now(), Now());'
    FROM inserted    

END

GO
```

Comment: I agree that sing cursors seems like a pretty bad idea. Initially I tried doing something like this, but there must have been some bad syntax somewhere that made me think that iteration through all rows would not happen.

Comment: Glad to help ;-)