# Fire a trigger on every insert to update a table with calculate tf-idf

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a SQL Server database which has terms which come from an ASP.NET C# program as a list of words by this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTerms]
    (@dt AS dbo.EngTerms READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AllDocs FLOAT, @DocsWithText FLOAT,  
            @TF FLOAT, @IDF FLOAT, @Weight FLOAT, @Index_ID INT;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.EnIndex (Term, TF, IDF, Weight, Doc_ID) 
        SELECT Term, TF, IDF, Weight, Doc_ID 
        FROM @dt;
```

After inserting these terms I need to calculate the `IDF` and `Weight` for each one of them by a trigger which update every inserted line with a formula and update the row.

Until now I only got this which only update the last row:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateIndex] 
ON [dbo].[EnIndex]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @AllDocs FLOAT, @DocsWithText FLOAT,  
            @TF FLOAT, @IDF FLOAT, @Weight FLOAT, @Index_ID INT;

    SET @Index_ID = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('EnIndex'));
    SET @AllDocs = (SELECT COUNT(Doc_ID) AS AllDocs FROM Document);
    SET @DocsWithText = (SELECT COUNT(Distinct(Doc_ID)) FROM EnIndex WHERE Index_ID = @Index_ID); 
    SET @TF = (SELECT DISTINCT TF FROM EnIndex WHERE Index_ID = @Index_ID);
    SET @IDF = (LOG(@AllDocs / @DocsWithText));
    SET @Weight = (@TF * @IDF);

    UPDATE EnIndex 
    SET IDF = @IDF, Weight = @Weight 
    WHERE Index_ID = @Index_ID;
END
```

Any suggestions, I read all questions on stackoverflow and they were very helpful to reach this step.

Comment: You have to use the `inserted` pseudo-table and then a cursor (or temp table loop) to process each row 1 at a time. Its not a recommended practise as its doesn't perform well in SQL Server - its the sort of thing better done in the client. But if you have to you have to. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805413/how-can-i-get-a-trigger-to-fire-on-each-inserted-row-during-an-insert-into-table

Comment: Also you seem to have an additional `Index_ID = @Index_ID` which doesn't appear to do anything?

Comment: I fixed it and I saw the link before but it didn't work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? You have to loop through the rows somehow, thats a good start, then adapt it to what you need. Start simple, build a loop which just prints the details from the row and work up from there.

Comment: why do you need a trigger?  if the process can be run manually then create a stored procedure that returns your results

Answer (score 0):

I write this to show you what seems like a significant mistake. Maybe your current trigger updates a row - but it does not look like it calculates an accurate value.

Firstly, you make a common mistake. Your trigger must work correctly when the inserted table contains any number of rows - from zero (yes!) to any number (not just one).

Next, your table has an identity column. You can access the value generated for each row in the inserted table to "know" which rows were inserted. Using ident_current is generally not a useful thing to do in most situations.

Next, you have this code:

```
SET @DocsWithText = (SELECT COUNT(Distinct(Doc_ID)) FROM EnIndex WHERE Index_ID = @Index_ID);
```

We know that the Index_ID variable contains the identity value of the (assumed single) inserted row. So you are counting values from a single row. Does that make any sense? Worse, you are counting distinct values. That is even more nonsense. The only value that can be computed from this is 1. You later divide another number by this value - which leaves that number unchanged. Don't know what you intended but this does nothing useful.

You have this:

```
SET @TF = (SELECT DISTINCT TF FROM EnIndex WHERE Index_ID = @Index_ID);
```

Again, we see the same flaw as discussed above. Your query selects a single row since it filters by the identity value. Using distinct is pointless as the query will only select one row. I get the feeling you add DISTINCT to your code without really thinking about it. Generally speaking, it is rare in my experience to need DISTINCT.

So I think it is time to take a step back and just develop your logic as a simple tsql script. Write it using a variable to which you assign the identity value from some random column you wish to use for testing. Retrieve and calculate the values needed to compute IDF and Weight correctly. Once you see that it does, you can then attempt to convert it to a well-written trigger that works with any number of inserted rows.

```
declare @id int, ...; 
declare @AllDocs int, @DocsWithText int; -- values that are counts from table  
declare @TF FLOAT, @IDF FLOAT, @Weight FLOAT; -- computed values

set @id = 34; -- set to an existing row for development 

set @AllDocs = (SELECT COUNT(Doc_ID) AS AllDocs FROM Document);
set @DocsWithText = ( ... ); 
set @TF = ( ... );
set @IDF = LOG(@AllDocs / @DocsWithText);
set @Weight = (@TF * @IDF);

select *, @AllDocs as AllDocs, @DocsWithText as DocsText, @TF as TF, 
    @IDF as IDF, @Weight as Wgt
from dbo.EnIndEx where Index_ID = @id;
```

That is just a start - you need to adjust it and work on the logic. Once that computes the correct value, you can then start to convert it to a trigger.

Comment: I used count and distinct on @DocsWithText when I was trying to pass the term (which could repeat)